# How to repair this error ? (Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at)

Tags: perl

#### This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;
my $file = "meme.txt" or die "KullanÄlÄyor: $0 FILE\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "AÃÄlamadÄ± '$file' $!";

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    chomp $line;

    foreach my $str ( split /\s+/, $line ) {
        $count{$str}++;
    }
}

foreach my $str ( sort keys %count ) {

    if ( -e "/home/%-31s %s\n", $str, $count{$str} and -d "/home/%-31s %s\n", $str, $count{$str} ) {
        print "Varmış böyle dizin\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Kapat kapat çok yazdı\n";
    }
}
```

It is working, but I have a error. How can I repair this error? Could you help me?

This error:

usrbin perl

> ```
> Found = in conditional, should be == at ./15.pl line 6. Useless use of
> private variable in void context at ./15.pl line 18. Useless use of
> private variable in void context at ./15.pl line 22. Unsuccessful stat
> on filename containing newline at ./15.pl line 16, <$fh> line 2.
> Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at ./15.pl line 16,
> <$fh> line 2. Varmış böyle dizin Unsuccessful stat on filename
> containing newline at ./15.pl line 16, <$fh> line 2. Unsuccessful stat
> on filename containing newline at ./15.pl line 16, <$fh> line 2.
> Varmış böyle dizin
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are building a string that is presumably supposed to be a path to a directory. This string

```
 "/home/%-31s %s\n"
```

has a newline at the end that you presumably don't intend

There are also a number of other problems with your program, which I suggest should be written more like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';


my %count;
my $file = 'meme.txt';

{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "AÃÄlamadÄ± '$file': $!";

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        ++$count{$_} for split;
    }
}

for my $str ( sort keys %count ) {

    my $dir = sprintf '/home/%-31s %s', $str, $count{$str};

    if ( -d $dir ) {
        print "Varmış böyle dizin\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Kapat kapat çok yazdı\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote like that but this time not checking directory

Comment: I'm not surprised. I doubt if your `sprintf` pattern is correct. Please give ***several*** examples of your input and the directories that exist

Comment: @MusaYıldırım: Please give many examples of your input and output, and the paths to the real directories that they are supposed to match. Birçok sizin giriş ve çıkış örnekleri ve onlar maç gerekiyordu gerçek dizinlerine yolları verin

Comment: for example takipsarayi, neguzel @Borodin

Comment: @MusaYıldırım: That is only one example. I need to see the contents of `meme.txt`. And please show the real directories that look like `/home/%-31s %s`. Bu sadece bir örnektir. Ben `meme.txt` içeriğini görmek gerekir. Ve `/home/%-31s %s` gibi görünen gerçek dizinleri göstermek lütfen .

Comment: my file https://notepad.cc/meme-txt @Borodin

Comment: And what do the directory names look like?

Comment: There are directory names it depends @Borodin

Comment: I'm waiting your answer, didnt you do it? @Borodin

Comment: @MusaYıldırım: I need several examples of the directory names that are supposed to match the contents of `meme.txt`. You didn't give them to me

Comment: I Gave you didnt see notepad.cc/meme-txt

Comment: @MusaYıldırım: I saw that, and I need to know what real directory names correspond to those strings

Comment: These're real directory names

Comment: @MusaYıldırım: Yes, and what are they? One of your errors is *"Unsuccessful stat on filename"*, and that is probably because the name isn't being found, so what directories do exist?

Answer (score 0):

This apparently occurs when there is *any* error in the operation and the filename contains a newline character "/n". To fix this, run the filename through chomp(). That will remove the newline character and should stop the error.

Comment: I did but Its not repair, do you have a another way ?